# Is zero a valid exponent for a public RSA key?

Tags: rsa

I'm having an issue with a key created by the manufacturer of an equipment. Checking the details of the key I've noticed that it's exponent is zero. Is this a valid exponent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zero is definitely never a valid public exponent for RSA!

As an exponent, zero cause all positive integers to become one (zero to the power of zero is mathematically invalid). Therefore, it can be considered (in the domain of positive integers) as a constant function.

I suggest dump the DER-encoded public key, parse it according to ASN.1 syntax, and analyze it thoroughly. What's more, consider black-list this vendor.

Comment: If the key is in a usual format, it cal likely be examined [there](https://lapo.it/asn1js/)